# jQuery clone() is appending to multiple elements instead of just one

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to make clonable form fields that get wrapped in to the div. I am able to clone the element but the problem is if I have multiple groups of similar fields, it is adding fields to all other groups regardless instead of only to the group for the button I clicked.

How can I clone fields only for the current `$(this)` element and not for others?

```js
let cloneInput = $('.clonedInput');
let btnAdd = $('.btnAdd');
let btnDel = $('.btnDel');

btnAdd.on('click', function(event) {
  $(this).parent().siblings('.gs-customer-form-group').children().last().clone().appendTo('.gs-customer-form-group');

});
```

```css
.gs-customer-field-box {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: sans-serif
}

.gs-customer-btn-group {
  margin: 20px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.btnDel {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btnAdd {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="gs-customer-field-box product-singular">
  <h6>Add Customer Details</h6>
  <div class="gs-customer-form-group" id="gs-customer-form-group">
    <div id="entry1" class="clonedInput gs-customer-fields">
      <input class="gs-field customer-name" type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Name">
      <input class="gs-field customer-email" type="email" name="email[]" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="gs-customer-btn-group">
    <span class="gs-customer-delete btnDel" id="btnDel1" disabled="disabled">delete</span>
    <span class="gs-customer-add btnAdd" id="btnAdd1">add</span>
  </div>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="gs-customer-field-box product-singular">
  <h6>Add Customer Details</h6>
  <div class="gs-customer-form-group" id="gs-customer-form-group">
    <div id="entry2" class="clonedInput gs-customer-fields">
      <input class="gs-field customer-name" type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Name">
      <input class="gs-field customer-email" type="email" name="email[]" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="gs-customer-btn-group">
    <span class="gs-customer-delete btnDel" id="btnDel2" disabled="disabled">delete</span>
    <span class="gs-customer-add btnAdd" id="btnAdd2">add</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to the `.appendTo('.gs-customer-form-group')` call. This appends the cloned content in to *every* `.gs-customer-form-group` element. You need to only append to the one related to the clicked `span`. You already have a reference to that element from `siblings()`, so you can put it in a variable for use later:

```js
let cloneInput = $('.clonedInput');
let btnAdd = $('.btnAdd');
let btnDel = $('.btnDel');

btnAdd.on('click', function(event) {
  let $group = $(this).parent().siblings('.gs-customer-form-group');
  $group.children().last().clone().appendTo($group);
});
```

```css
.gs-customer-field-box {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: sans-serif
}

.gs-customer-btn-group {
  margin: 20px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.btnDel {
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btnAdd {
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.active {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="gs-customer-field-box product-singular">
  <h6>Add Customer Details</h6>
  <div class="gs-customer-form-group" id="gs-customer-form-group">
    <div id="entry1" class="clonedInput gs-customer-fields">
      <input class="gs-field customer-name" type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Name">
      <input class="gs-field customer-email" type="email" name="email[]" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="gs-customer-btn-group">
    <span class="gs-customer-delete btnDel" id="btnDel1" disabled="disabled">delete</span>
    <span class="gs-customer-add btnAdd" id="btnAdd1">add</span>
  </div>
</div>

<hr/>

<div class="gs-customer-field-box product-singular">
  <h6>Add Customer Details</h6>
  <div class="gs-customer-form-group" id="gs-customer-form-group">
    <div id="entry2" class="clonedInput gs-customer-fields">
      <input class="gs-field customer-name" type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Name">
      <input class="gs-field customer-email" type="email" name="email[]" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="gs-customer-btn-group">
    <span class="gs-customer-delete btnDel" id="btnDel2" disabled="disabled">delete</span>
    <span class="gs-customer-add btnAdd" id="btnAdd2">add</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```js
let cloneInput = $('.clonedInput');
let btnAdd = $('.btnAdd');
let btnDel = $('.btnDel');

btnAdd.on('click', function(event){
  $(this).parent().siblings('.gs-customer-form-group').children().last().clone().appendTo($(this).parent().siblings('.gs-customer-form-group'));

});
```

```css
.gs-customer-field-box{
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: sans-serif
}

.gs-customer-btn-group{
  margin: 20px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.btnDel{
  color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btnAdd{
  color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.active{
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gs-customer-field-box product-singular">
  <h6>Add Customer Details</h6>
  <div class="gs-customer-form-group" id="gs-customer-form-group">
    <div id="entry1" class="clonedInput gs-customer-fields">
      <input class="gs-field customer-name" type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Name">
      <input class="gs-field customer-email" type="email" name="email[]" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="gs-customer-btn-group">
    <span class="gs-customer-delete btnDel" id="btnDel1" disabled="disabled">delete</span>
    <span class="gs-customer-add btnAdd" id="btnAdd1">add</span>
  </div>
</div>

<hr />

<div class="gs-customer-field-box product-singular">
  <h6>Add Customer Details</h6>
  <div class="gs-customer-form-group" id="gs-customer-form-group">
    <div id="entry2" class="clonedInput gs-customer-fields">
      <input class="gs-field customer-name" type="text" name="name[]" placeholder="Name">
      <input class="gs-field customer-email" type="email" name="email[]" placeholder="Email">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="gs-customer-btn-group">
    <span class="gs-customer-delete btnDel" id="btnDel2" disabled="disabled">delete</span>
    <span class="gs-customer-add btnAdd" id="btnAdd2">add</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. For my knowledge, this is the only way, or is there any more robust ad optimized way to do it? If not, then I will do it in your way.

Comment: @CodeLover For my knowledge it's the only way. I don't know how this could be optimized as it selects the .gs-customer-form-group based on the button that got clicked.

Comment: I see. I am not an expert in jQuery so just trying to learn the better way to do it.